# Importing data from Excel File to Database Using OpenPyxl and sqlite3 in Spyder

Tags: python, sqlite, openpyxl

I'm trying to import data from a Excel .xlsx files into databases .db I have created using sqlite3 and openpyxl, on Spyder. I am allowed to use Panda if needed. This is for an assignment, so I cannot use possible 'more efficient' methods other than those I've mentioned above. My problem is with the actual importing of excel data into the databases. I have set up tables and column-titles using simple command-line prompts (CMD) as a last resort, but need to show the code when submitting.
Below is my code for this, using Spyder. (I saved this file in the correct folder that has the excel files and .db file in it)

```
import sqlite3
import openpyxl
connection = sqlite3.connect('createdb_food.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('inspections.xlsx')
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('violations.xlsx')
```

(I then write sql_commands and execute for creating tables << works)
(I now attempt to import the data into the corresponding files... I will show code for VIOLATIONS.xslx one, as less code..but both excel imports are the same with different variables)

```
sheet2 = wb2['violations']
values2 = []
for row in sheet2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=906015, max_col=5):
    for cell in row:
        if len(values2) == 5:
            sql_command = """
            INSERT INTO violations(points, serial_number, violation_code, violation_description, violation_status)
            VALUES(values2[0], values2[1], values2[2], values2[3], values2[4]
            );"""
            cursor.execute(sql_command)
            values2 = []
        values2.append(cell.value)
```

**[(CHECK EDIT BELOW)]** for above code change ^

Then I save and commit changes and close the connection.

```
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I am using utf-8.
Current error in Spyder reads: "self.ws._cells[(cell['row'], cell['column'])] = c || MemoryError".

I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

**[(EDIT)]**: I have changed some code to the following...

```
sheet2 = wb2['violations']
values2 = []
wb2_row_count = sheet2.max_row
wb2_col_count = sheet2.max_column
for row in sheet2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=906015, max_col=5):
    if len(values2) == 5:
        sql_command = """
        INSERT INTO violations(?,?,?,?,?
        );"""
        cursor.execute(sql_command)
        values2 = []
    for cell in row:
        values2.append(cell.value)
    cursor.execute(values2)
```

*ERROR MESSAGE:*

File "C:\Users[name]\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_reader.py", line 139, in parse
    for _, element in it:

MemoryError

Comment: This ***"Current error in Spyder"***, have noting to do with your shown code. Remove `[spyder]` and `[Excel]` tag. [Edit] your question and show the Error you get from `.execute(...`.

Comment: Use read-only mode.